# How can I fix null object being sent from PUT json in Postman?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

I am PUTing json in the body from postman in hopes of updating an entity called `MusicListListItem`.

When I debug, I am finding that the `MusicListListItem` item is `null`.

Here is my method on on my `MusicListsController`:

```
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    [Route("API/[Controller]/UpdateMusicListListItem")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutMusicListListItem(int id, [FromBody]MusicListListItem item)
    {

        MusicListListItem myMLLI = item; 
        if (id != item.MusicListListItemId)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        _context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return NoContent();
    }
```

and here is the json i put into Postman's Body section with JSON(application/json) selected:

```
{
    "musicListListItemId": 4,
    "musicListId": 1,
    "listItemId": 1019,
    "listItem": {
        "artist": null,
        "listItemId": 1019,
        "title": "test33_tryAddRelation",
        "dateCreated": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "musicListListItem": []
    },
    "rank": 2,
    "comments": null,
    "imageUrl": null,
    "dateModified": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "deleted": false
}
```

I expect the API Controller's `PutMusicListListItem` method to receive the `MusicListListItem` object from the body of Postman's PUT request, but it comes back as `null`.

I eventually get a

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

error.

Here is the additional information that was requested:

The musicListListItem object definition:

```
using MusicListsApp.Domain;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Text;

namespace Domain
{
    public class MusicListListItem
    {
        public int MusicListListItemId { get; set; }

        public int MusicListId { get; set; }

        public int ListItemId { get; set; }

        public virtual MusicList MusicList { get; set; }

        public virtual ListItem ListItem { get; set; }

        public int Rank { get; set; }

        public string Comments { get; set; }

        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }

        public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    }
}
```

A screenshot of Postman:

[image]

Comment: So - can you post the definition of `MusicListListItem `.  Also - what exactly does the postman request look like?  How have you specified the JSON in the body?  Did you set a Content-Type on the header (to application/json).  It sounds like the Postman request is not sending the request in the way that your controller is expecting.  We need more details.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply! I added the additional information you requested to the original post.

Comment: You probably need to set the content-type to application/Json in the request

Comment: The content-type was set to application/json on the rightmost tab of the body page and in the header page of the Postman interface. However, your comment asking about the definition of MusicListListItem prompted me to create a method that returns the json of a MusicListListItem where I got a simpler definition back. I used this simpler json object to successfully put to the controller url with Postman. So thanks for helping me think this through.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully PUT to the API by using a simpler MusicListListItem json object that I obtained by creating a GETMusicListListItemById method:

```
{
"musicListListItemId": 4,
"musicListId": 1,
"listItemId": 1019,
"musicList": null,
"listItem": null,
"rank": 2,
"comments": null,
"imageUrl": null,
"dateModified": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
"deleted": false
}
```